# "'React/RCTViewManager.h' file not found" How should I add Header Search Paths?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding this Header Search Paths issue. So the original issue is that I am adding this package to my React Native project: https://github.com/manse/react-native-brightcove-player

I have followed the installation instructions to the best of my knowledge but when I try to build for iOS I get an error:
`'React/RCTViewManager.h' file not found` in react-native-brightcove-player.xcodeproj/BrightcovePlayerManager.h:

```
#import <React/RCTViewManager.h>

@interface BrightcovePlayerManager : RCTViewManager

@end
```

So I have read that I need to edit "Header Search Paths" for this project (aka react-native-brightcove-player.xcodeproj).

sources:

https://forums.expo.io/t/how-do-i-manually-add-pods-headers-public-to-the-header-search-paths-configuration/2427/11

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/expokit/#changing-native-dependencies

I have tried adding $(SRCROOT)/Pods/Headers/Public along with {the-actual-path-to-my-ios-project}/Pods/Headers/Public but I still keep getting the same error on build. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Apple's tools make no sense, and are terrible :(